# jQuery price error with ie7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I have some javascript that calculates a price and updates a div. However in ie7 the div calc_sprice displays €NaN.

I think it occurred when I put price formatting in. But I cant see the issue. It works on all other browser though.

```
            function formatPrice (price) {
                var dplaces = price == parseInt(price, 10) ? 0 : 2;
                price = price.toFixed(dplaces);

                return price

            }

            function calc_supp(showdiv){

                    var sup   = $(showdiv+' .rate_data').attr('sup');
                    var asup  = $(showdiv+' .rate_data').attr('asup');
                    var csup  = $(showdiv+' .rate_data').attr('csup');

                    //var total_price = $(showdiv+' #total_price').val();
                    var total_price = $(showdiv+' #tmp_price').val();
                    total_price = Number(total_price);

                    var tot_adults = 0;
                    var tot_childs = 0;
                    var rooms = 0;

                        $(showdiv + ' select.adu').each(function(){
                            var tot_as = $(this).val();         
                            tot_adults += Number(tot_as);
                            rooms +=1;
                        });

                        $(showdiv + ' select.chi').each(function(){
                            var tot_cs = $(this).val();         
                            tot_childs += Number(tot_cs);
                        });

                    var supp = rooms*sup; // total supplement

                    var total_asupp = Number(tot_adults * asup);
                    var total_csupp = Number(tot_childs * csup);

                    var total_sup = Number(supp + total_asupp + total_csupp);
                    var total_total = Number(total_sup + total_price);
                    //alert(supp);

                    $(showdiv + ' .calc_supp span').html(formatPrice(total_sup));
                    $(showdiv + ' .calc_sprice span').html(formatPrice(total_total));
                    $(showdiv+' #total_price').val(formatPrice(total_total));


            }
```

Comment: `$(showdiv+' #tmp_price')` ... you don't have multiple elements with the ID `tmp_price` do you? If so...that could be your problem. If not, you don't really need the `showdiv` bit in there.

Comment: Yes actualy I do. Would that cause problems in only ie7? It wasnt an issue before as far as I can remember

Comment: Not sure, but it isn't valid. An ID is supposed to uniquely identify an element. Use classes if you want to have more than one. A browser may have optimizations in place, built on the assumption that there is only one.

Comment: Nice one, thanks, didn't spot that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id was being used instead of class. All other browser had no problem with this so didn't spot it until I tested in ie7